# Dynamic ListAdapter List (TextView) click with extends AsyncTask

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-asynctask

Hi i need textview click event

I load list data from database by using cursor :

`HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();`

Also the data base fetch event done by using 
extends AsyncTask

The all above tasks under a tabLayout -> MyListFragment

And i call the Asynctask at public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)

When i try to write `onClick` List Item nothing happened so please find me out the list text click event and later i will open a new fragment on click

[image: Need Text click]

StatusFragment.java

```
public class StatusFragment extends ListFragment  {


// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private JSONArray mComments = null;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

private static final String TAG_CAT = "cat";

public StatusFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
    return rootView;

}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    new Loadfromdb().execute();

}
public class Loadfromdb extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        addlist();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        updateList();

    }
}

private void updateList() {

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), mCommentList,
            R.layout.fragment_status, new String[] {
            TAG_CAT}, new int[] {
            R.id.categ });

    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Am Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    setListAdapter(adapter);


}


public void addlist() {

    mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    DatabaseHandler myDbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    myDbHelper.open();

    Cursor c = myDbHelper.fetchOption();

    if(c!=null ){
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(  c.isAfterLast() == false )
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String des = c.getString(0).toString();
            map.put(TAG_CAT, des);
            mCommentList.add(map);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Am Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

activity_list.xml

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:stretchColumns="0,1">
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/categ"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Am new to android can u post a sample ans instead of suggestion

Comment: I found the Ans :) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

To detect a click on your listView row instead of using `onClickListener` you'll need to use `onItemClickListener`.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Add action here: e.g. open new fragment.            
    }
});
```

Since in your case, you are using a `ListFragment`, you can override `onListItemClick()`.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

Comment: where to put this code? did u see my StatusFragment.java

Comment: I've edited my answer for your implementation. The second part will be what you need.

Comment: Can you update your code sample with the implementation? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Am not using custom adapter

Comment: I updated the post with your code chk it... still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
    ((ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = "
                    + id);
        }
    });
    return rootView;

}
```

Comment: OnItemClickListener not found so i import AdapterView.OnItemClickListener();

Comment: Also it gives me the following error  " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created " on this line 
" getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {"

Comment: you can also write ((ListView)rootView.fingViewById(R.id.list)).setOnItemClickListener(...)

Comment: what error you have when you try find listView by id ?